# Extension method using non Instantiated object, i.e. String.F()

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

At a previous organization, we implemented an extension method that created a shorthand for String.Format.  The method was called "String.F". However I do not seem to be able to get this to work.  A former co-worker gave me the following code which I am listing below along with my own test method.  In the function 'Test()', "String.F" throws and error and is not displayed in intellisence.  I would ask if this is not possible, but I have writen code using a call to this method.  Is this only possilble when using an instantiated string?  Thanks.

```
public static class MyExtensions {
    public static string F(this string target, params object[] args) {
        return "hello";
    }
}

class TestExtensions {
    public string Test() {
        return String.F("test:{0}", "test");
    }
}
```

Comment: This should _not even compile_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do extension method and use it in a static context. Extension methods can be used only as instance methods.

You can do

```
public static string F(this string target, params object[] args) {
        return String.Format(target, args);
}
```

and use it like this

```
"test:{0}".F("test");
```

Comment: First, extension methods *are* static methods. They can even be called on a null object. The method in question can also called like that: MyExtensions.F(test:{0}, "test")

Comment: @codymanix Extension methods are static and can be called in as a static method as you mention, no questions about it. But if you are going to call extension method that way, it defeats the purpose of having it as an extension method.

Comment: Sure this isn't the preferred way to call an extension method, but you claimed that it wouldn't possible which is wrong.

Comment: Defeats the purpose? How about extending a class you have no access to modify? So far, extension method is the only way I've found, and it would really nice if it could be done. I'd like to be able to use it like `String.F("test");` in which case `target` would be null.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're invoking String.F, when the class that owns the method is MyExtensions; not String...if you want to invoke it like that, it should be MyExtensions.F("test{0}", "test")

As others have mentioned, though, while this is perfectly valid, it seems to be sidestepping the very thing that makes extension methods distinct.

Doing "test{0}".F("test");  should give the same result as MyExtensions.F("test{0}", "test"); If F wasn't set up as an extension method, only the latter approach would be valid.

Comment: In the end either of these solutions would work, however the point of the exercise was to create a simple shorthand.  So I would either use "test{0}".F("test") or create a class with a short name "s" with the static Method "F(string, params)".  I guess this makes me a lazy programmer though!

Comment: @dave: yeah, either approach is fine, but if you're marking methods as extensions, then it's probably prefered to use them as such...I offered my answer mostly in response to Bala R's answer which seemed to give the impression that the original error was one of invaild usage rather than simply a case of a mistyped name.  (through comments he's cleared this up, though).    To be clear, I'm not nec. advocating invoking the extension method directly via its container class, but I wanted the point out that what you were doing was still fine (well, aside from referencing the wrong class name :) )